# C# Form opens up multiple times on new detected record

Tags: c#, database, notifications

I am setting up a Notification when new record has been detected in a database.

**Notification**

```
private int RecordCount = int.MinValue;

//Notification
private void Notification(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int newCount;
    using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from table where priority = 'High';", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            newCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }

    if (RecordCount == int.MinValue) RecordCount = newCount;
    int diff = newCount - RecordCount;
    if (diff != 0)
    {

        Forms.Notification.High_Priority_Notificaiton form = new Forms.Notification.High_Priority_Notificaiton();
        form.ShowDialog();

        //Update new number
        RecordCount = newCount;
    }
}
```

**Where I start it**

```
public Dashboard()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 5000;
    timer.Elapsed += Notification;
    timer.Start();

}
```

When a new record has been detected. The form opens up every time.

[image]

**My non working solution**

I have decided to implement this code, to check if the form is already opened.

```
//Check if form is already open
private TForm findOrOpenForm<TForm>() where TForm : Form, new()
{
    var found = Application.OpenForms.OfType<TForm>().FirstOrDefault();
    if (!(found is null))
    {
        found.BringToFront();
        if (found.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
        {
            found.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        found = new TForm();
        found.Show();
    }
    return found; // This allows further actions outside of `findOrOpenForm`; you may not need it.
}
```

And use it like so...

```
if (RecordCount == int.MinValue) RecordCount = newCount;
int diff = newCount - RecordCount;
if (diff != 0)
{

    findOrOpenForm<Forms.Notification.High_Priority_Notificaiton>();

    //Update new number
    RecordCount = newCount;
}
```

This solution, prevents the multiple form opening but this time, it freezes the whole application.

I cannot close it as the wait cursor is showing and need to task manager out myself.

Even the text does not show up, just a blank red screen.

[image]

Comment: As per the docs `If the SynchronizingObject property is null, the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.` You may wish to try `timer.SynchronizingObject = this;`.

Comment: @mjwills Not quite sure what this means.

Comment: Did you try `timer.SynchronizingObject = this;`?

Comment: @mjwills I'll try when I am back at work.

Answer (score 1):

place following two lines at global level in

```
High_Priority_Notificaiton form = null;
public static bool NotificationOpened = false;
```

replace your Notification method in Dashboard.cs with the following

```
        private void Notification(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            int newCount = 0;
            
            using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString.ConnString))
            {
                using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) from table where priority = 'High';", conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    newCount = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
                }
            }

            if (RecordCount == int.MinValue) RecordCount = newCount;
            int diff = newCount - RecordCount;
            //if (diff != 0)
            {
                if (!NotificationOpened)
                {
                    NotificationOpened = true;
                    form = new High_Priority_Notificaiton();
                    form.ShowDialog();
                }

                //Update new number
                RecordCount = newCount;
            }
        }
```

Register form closed event handler in High_Priority_Notification form and place this line in form closed event handler.

```
Dashboard.NotificationOpened = false;
```

Now your code should work as expected

Comment: I have edited the answer. you can review and make changes accordingly. I have tested it on myside and it is working. @LV98

Comment: Notification does not show up at all. Why did you comment out `if (diff != 0)`

Comment: I commented this just for my testing. you can uncomment it. And i have tested and its 100% working solution. Recheck if you are missing something